# How can you perform an acid-base titration with antacids if substances, like aluminium hydroxide, are insoluble?

Tags: acid-base, ph, titration

I am trying to perform an experiment in order to determine the efficiency of different antacids. An online search later shows that you add an HCl solution in a solution created with a base/antacid. However, the substances do not dissolve in water and hence precipitate in the bottom. Is there a step I am missing?

Comment: Solids can react, so if you design the titration appropriately, this will still work.

Comment: In order to have the antacid neutralization reaction go fast add a known amount of excess acid and back titrate the extra acid with NaOH.

Comment: Grind the solid well and stir or swirl as you titrate.

Comment: So it doesn't matter if there is still solid in the solution? Just add acid until everything dissolves and then do the back-titration with NaOH?

Comment: That's what I would do, just like MaxW's comment. Good note by bpedit too; get that surface area up by grinding it until the consistency is as close to a "flour" as possible, then stir throughout dissolution and titration.